# Search for a date as you type in a text box>Active X Controls

Tags: excel, vba, date

I am new to vba coding.

I am trying to make a text box that searches for the date as you type. For example if I have a table with many dates, as I type "2015" I would like it to show me all the dates with 2015 data. or If I type 04/2015 then show me all the data for April 2015

I have tried many codes that filter a you type but it seems that they do not work for dates.

Note: If this is too difficult to code, then an alternative option for me would be to dedicate two cells in the worksheet so that if I write two dates in these cells it would filter and show me the data between those two dates.

Thanks :)

[My WorkSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erK5C.png)

CODE

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    Dim filterInput As Range
    Dim filterRange As Range
    
    Set filterInput = Range("D5")
    Set filterRange = Range("I10:I39")
    
    filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria:="*" & filterInput & "*", _
                           VisibleDropDown:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: "I have tried many codes" - what *specific* codes did you try (maybe pick one and post your version of it) and what *specific* problem(s) did you have when trying to use it?  Questions without code here tend to get closed as "too broad" or "needs debugging details".  People are more likely to help you if you show what you tried.

Comment: I looked at a youtube channel doing what im  looking for but when I tried it it doesnt work. I have added the code in my original Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may get you started:

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim filterInput As Range
    Dim filterRange As Range, vFilt
    
    Set filterRange = Me.Range("D9:D37")
    vFilt = Trim(Me.Range("D5").Value) 'TextBox1 is linked to D5
    Debug.Print vFilt
    
    If vFilt Like "##" Then vFilt = "20" & vFilt
    
    If vFilt Like "20##" Then
        'filter year only
        filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                Criteria2:=Array(0, "12/31/" & vFilt)
    ElseIf vFilt Like "#/####" Or vFilt Like "##/####" Or _
           vFilt Like "#/##" Or vFilt Like "##/##" Then
        'filter month/year
        filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                Criteria2:=Array(1, LastDayOfMonth(vFilt))
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        filterRange.Parent.ShowAllData
    End If
End Sub

Function LastDayOfMonth(v)
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(v, "/")
    If arr(1) Like "##" Then arr(1) = "20" & arr(1)
    LastDayOfMonth = Application.EoMonth(DateSerial(arr(1), arr(0), 1), 0)
    LastDayOfMonth = Format(LastDayOfMonth, "mm/dd/yyyy")
End Function
```

Filtering on dates: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/filter-dates/

Comment: Thank you so much. you are amazing. I hope both side of your pillow is cold :)

Comment: Good to hear it's working.  I learned some too while putting that together.